# IDs and child combinator simplified

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have 7 ID's with identical child combinators, how can I simplify it so I don't have to write it out like the following:

```
#section-monday > div > div > div:nth-child(1),
#section-tuesday > div > div > div:nth-child(1),
#section-wednesday > div > div > div:nth-child(1),
... {}
```

Can I somehow group the IDs and follow them only once with child combinator?

Like

```
"#section-monday, #section-tuesday, #section-wednesday" > div > div > div:nth-child(1){}
```

Comment: Use a class instead, you can put the class on the child you are trying to target to make it the simplest

Comment: I can't use classes, is it possible with ID?

Comment: `[id^=section-] > div > div > div:nth-child(1) `  It will select ids starting with `section-`

Comment: You should post the markup so we can get a better picture of the situation. There are other ways of doing this but with only css, we would have to assume a lot of things, better to put up the html

Comment: @G-Cyr this works for me, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use part of the id text as selector,
but you should use a class in cases like this

```css
[id*="section-"] > div > div > div:nth-child(1){
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="section-monday">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        :D
      </div>
      <div>
        :(
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
<div id="section-tuesday">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        :D
      </div>
      <div>
        :(
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
<div id="section-monday">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        :D
      </div>
      <div>
        :(
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
<div id="section-wednesday">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        :D
      </div>
      <div>
        :(
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This would select **all** elements that have `section-` in the id. This could have unintended consequences depending on the HTML. For instance, this approach would target an element with the id `header-section-top`.